# Display blob value in VF page and render as PDF

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, blob, blob.topdf

I am trying to display a PDF stored in static resource and  passing the blob as a string to VF page and late rendering as PDF

```
<apex:page controller="DataDisplayController" renderAs="pdf">
  {!PDFData}
<!--<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!PDFData}" ></iframe>--> 
<!--iframe doesn't display the data  --> 
</apex:page>
```

Displays only the Blob value in VF Page but I need the data from the blob

> JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjk2IDAgb2JqIDw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDQzNzQyNC9PIDEwNy9FID   ------- Blob recieved in VF page

The string is valid UTF-8 stirng -->  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(csvBlob);

How Am i supposed to display the blob data in VF page

Comment: You can't render a PDF in a PDF. The underlying rendering engine (Flying Saucer) does not support this sort of functionality. I'm not sure what you're *trying* to do, but this path is a dead end.

Comment: oh Okay, but Can I display the Blob data in VF page. Can you suggest a workaround for that?

Comment: You can only display certain types of Blob files, such as a PNG or JPG. You can't put in any arbitrary type.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>'Hello, world!' base64 example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>'Hello, world!' example</h1>
    <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px  solid black"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.487/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <script id="script">
      var pdfData = atob(
        'JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNCAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggMTc5Mi9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU+\nPnN0cmVhbQp4nL2az2tcVRTHXwUVZiP6D+RttC3S5N2f855BRFEDVadJZqqETmsbm0YlaWuToEXx\nB7VQCaNd2MSNhS7EhbuuxIXQv8CFGze6kYI7XUURpN4fM+/dibn33HNbZGhz29w333s+c++558cU\nOckPkbzIRSXU36+ttt5qPdNrMZkLUeW9063neq25Fs0P6//V84p8NLu32pp6nuSkyHtnWgcO9t7U\nc5sp5s2ch1ghJ0UuWDVJuX2W5tQ8W5gZF5ZbBzYmPrx55OetN64szX6wNNX56ez93aP6jYt8eY83\nP3Zc/TxtFueXJUWR87I9KehIlPBx0e7RIy/5RUj+tvrN4eH8+ZmRqmTamqLK1RTJh+OVVtf/ANdT\n1MRVPeTtUg2D87UAbzcCehx6gDgKZEwiClQpcy5CnF7NFtuf71x5MZEVxhSz+oYVj2PFHQEOsxop\nkDGJ+E1FQ7AWfuz1L6SSQhhi1t6QInGkiCNAIkhxhxTB7ipWhUDpI790e3kilRXCFLP6mhUro1ix\nshHQY5AVaVg1EtGsJMTqvXfnH09khTHFrL5hJeJYCUdAwKxGCmRMIpoVg1itPjrgqawQppjVN6xo\nHCvqCNAIVsJhRVGspFIoIFbd6Y3tQbX41bUslRjCIGNDTYxWUcRo1QjoMUiMNsQaiVhitB0itnlj\n/hFNbfGF5alBlUgMY5CxoSEm44hJR0DCxEYKZEwi9jxSHoweLl+dOTn9xZeprBCmmNU3rFgcK+YI\nsAhW0mHF0NEDJcHo4cGV31JBIewwS29AFXGgnJiXAjEvcRTImETspiJ6G3o5vf/D/PVTD31yK5UV\nwhSz+poV4UUMK8JJLaDHICsnfG8koljRgqo8p5zkdXJF6Dis7Z25tRP3dU51bi7sv3Ru8anu9KVz\nn/1ybd9yf31rdm6l+1dn7ezV6+f7/T86hwa/d7L5B05s48ESJzESxgQoMfLnLWENm1BYDSihULNq\nDT1G5ka0UnBFCG5W7XoVGU2FhzHMn8gAGtzRAHIMC8yBh0yWVKjJaQje5red/vrrl5N5GVuoiLHF\nn84AGsTRAPIMNavWMGNcykSl0CLB9PLk/pQsgJpFWVysqCJw+U0BNIijAeBSs2oNM8bh0rFmeHst\nrOFRMXNTDVFJEoHKbwagQRwNCJUkjYYeI1G1Obiz5v7emEjLx5ksamScxxQv/OYAGsTRAJCpWbWG\nGeOQmUeCuysjytuXWVv9VD4/a+PBcY71yH6jAA3iaADgrKd3vD4OHNFZZxUERxUwosAV+k+y80c4\nZn99JqxhCydWAyqcWC/ZeExkDYgVAiiY6XL1ibVXZo7fHjybfAUgDpDfoLCGhWY1IGh2Dzf7GQmN\nCl05C+21+Zc/utj5+k5/cet7/WP9Tv/M7MzyxEL/4NJ5tQdpVqph6ha0ltpTFVMi3LvsBWgIRwOo\nR+nTOtIwY1xpTVgfC/ZMOr++sw+PTJh00OYHUlfwwPzAH7uHNWwYbTXAhgNrN90ZNUbmB5IbkWD6\nZW4HZpwezaQasUym5K2yxtc2iwT7Tl7TwhoWn9WA8KlZtYYeI/ENd1yw+6Q7T4PHun+m7jjMbvAn\nPIAGdzSgxo35KJyPBZdUCS7hUG5l5eFPv+n8s3nrLrAhTPJHDIAGcTSgHo5B5WDDRSUWG9yRqi+H\nZG4Imywrx1+DN6zVsPeO1QD7OYZVww15ww65BbtTo5p4WocKb5L/mgM0hKMBtXYMKgcb7iod3gv/\nQ+UI77P9DgjQ4I4G4BHsXeDcCzgnJ7lJisPpF1ev0dVap2LJABHG+V0RoEEcDcA1WGgOQJy7M1s2\nGBingrIH1RoR43v2PkSAhnA0gIOq4Yw0zBh3UDllOWNAml+onSbVa1KNWXKygDDK3/cFNKijAbRi\nLSwHHK63zNXb6zpWAJzMhAJWGmzJNXGMSf7mb1jD9mOtBtSPtagabMgGMzcd5nC6kIoKY4a/6wto\nSEcDaMdaPA4qXGdZH03KgaMpjePnao/RTCSDQxjlbwEDGszRANqzFpYDDtlm1ssi99b5443wt4AB\nDSfFhXqzFo4DKqLNvOufkW1ARVVdLGW7JrrrC6zdnc6TH4e++BdZBKxUdM0COnXtNBDpxEmVDOix\nH7uxeDGtx26L9faD5Ka/AX2Qugkw6oHrMdxmtxq2z241oD47dzT4mEak5yYAsIQGgAMqbsf7jQhr\nWFBWAwJlT1Jzqjyg/MfePrD7k4ys6EInTX/1o/Nd9sRd7n/t54muUfOQULghFheKm+AU6IiYSnRy\n7oLIK/zlgHsX9tt8xYkscSUHLku4gcRVbJkQiuO7Yf4ORVgD0xvw14Eid5iaLQidrMqaGPtvaUt/\nEW/16RUeqglGxxdazu8J1X4uzIuYDL0KfVSO5L97XgKPCmVuZHN0cmVhbQplbmRvYmoKMSAwIG9i\nago8PC9Hcm91cDw8L1R5cGUvR3JvdXAvQ1MvRGV2aWNlUkdCL1MvVHJhbnNwYXJlbmN5Pj4vUGFy\nZW50IDUgMCBSL0NvbnRlbnRzIDQgMCBSL1R5cGUvUGFnZS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Qcm9jU2V0IFsv\nUERGIC9UZXh0IC9JbWFnZUIgL0ltYWdlQyAvSW1hZ2VJXS9Db2xvclNwYWNlPDwvQ1MvRGV2aWNl\nUkdCPj4vRm9udDw8L0YxIDIgMCBSL0YyIDMgMCBSPj4+Pi9NZWRpYUJveFswIDAgNTk1IDg0Ml0v\nUm90YXRlIDkwPj4KZW5kb2JqCjYgMCBvYmoKWzEgMCBSL1hZWiAwIDYwNSAwXQplbmRvYmoKMiAw\nIG9iago8PC9CYXNlRm9udC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EvVHlwZS9Gb250L0VuY29kaW5nL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNv\nZGluZy9TdWJ0eXBlL1R5cGUxPj4KZW5kb2JqCjcgMCBvYmoKPDwvRm9udEJCb3ggWy0yNSAtMjU0\nIDEwMDAgODgwXS9DYXBIZWlnaHQgODgwL1N0eWxlPDwvUGFub3NlKAEFAgIEAAAAAAAAACk+Pi9U\neXBlL0ZvbnREZXNjcmlwdG9yL1N0ZW1WIDkzL0Rlc2NlbnQgLTEyMC9GbGFncyA2L0ZvbnROYW1l\nL1NUU29uZy1MaWdodC9Bc2NlbnQgODgwL0l0YWxpY0FuZ2xlIDA+PgplbmRvYmoKOCAwIG9iago8\nPC9CYXNlRm9udC9TVFNvbmctTGlnaHQvQ0lEU3lzdGVtSW5mbzw8L09yZGVyaW5nKEdCMSkvUmVn\naXN0cnkoQWRvYmUpL1N1cHBsZW1lbnQgND4+L1R5cGUvRm9udC9TdWJ0eXBlL0NJREZvbnRUeXBl\nMC9Gb250RGVzY3JpcHRvciA3IDAgUi9EVyAxMDAwPj4KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwvRGVzY2Vu\nZGFudEZvbnRzWzggMCBSXS9CYXNlRm9udC9TVFNvbmctTGlnaHQtVW5pR0ItVUNTMi1IL1R5cGUv\nRm9udC9FbmNvZGluZy9VbmlHQi1VQ1MyLUgvU3VidHlwZS9UeXBlMD4+CmVuZG9iago1IDAgb2Jq\nCjw8L0lUWFQoMi4xLjcpL1R5cGUvUGFnZXMvQ291bnQgMS9LaWRzWzEgMCBSXT4+CmVuZG9iago5\nIDAgb2JqCjw8L05hbWVzWyhKUl9QQUdFX0FOQ0hPUl8wXzEpIDYgMCBSXT4+CmVuZG9iagoxMCAw\nIG9iago8PC9EZXN0cyA5IDAgUj4+CmVuZG9iagoxMSAwIG9iago8PC9OYW1lcyAxMCAwIFIvVHlw\nZS9DYXRhbG9nL1ZpZXdlclByZWZlcmVuY2VzPDwvUHJpbnRTY2FsaW5nL0FwcERlZmF1bHQ+Pi9Q\nYWdlcyA1IDAgUj4+CmVuZG9iagoxMiAwIG9iago8PC9DcmVhdG9yKEphc3BlclJlcG9ydHMgTGli\ncmFyeSB2ZXJzaW9uIDUuNi4wKS9Qcm9kdWNlcihpVGV4dCAyLjEuNyBieSAxVDNYVCkvTW9kRGF0\nZShEOjIwMTcxMjI5MTE0OTE0KzA4JzAwJykvQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlKEQ6MjAxNzEyMjkxMTQ5MTQr\nMDgnMDAnKT4+CmVuZG9iagp4cmVmCjAgMTMKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAxODc1\nIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDIxNjMgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMjYwNSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAw\nMDE1IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDI3MjkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMjEyOCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAw\nMDAyMjUxIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDI0NDIgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMjc5MiAwMDAwMCBuIAow\nMDAwMDAyODQ2IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDI4NzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMjk4NCAwMDAwMCBu\nIAp0cmFpbGVyCjw8L1Jvb3QgMTEgMCBSL0lEIFs8NzM3YjNiYTEyZTQ3ZjE4MDdlYjE1NDA1NjMw\nMDQyYWI+PDRiMzVlN2ZlOWU0YTM4YWU3ZDJiY2E1MTgzNmQ2NWZmPl0vSW5mbyAxMiAwIFIvU2l6\nZSAxMz4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgozMTUyCiUlRU9GCg=='
      );
      pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.487/pdf.worker.min.js';
      pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData}).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
        // Fetch the first page.
        pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
          var scale = 1.5;
          var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
          var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;
          var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
          };
          page.render(renderContext);
        });
      });
    </script>
    <hr>
    <h2>JavaScript code:</h2>
    <pre id="code"></pre>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('code').textContent =
      document.getElementById('script').text;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Code dumps make for poor answers. The explanation is as important as the solution. What was the problem OP was running into? What makes this approach different? Why would this work?